# Python list comprehension and variable creation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I am trying to make a variable 'listy' that stores all possible combinations of the numbers 6 , 9 and 20 in a given range.

I started with all numbers that are bigger than 5 and are divisible by 3 , then to this list I added a new list containing each element of the first list +20 and repeated the process one more time.

I want to create the list using only one line of code and list comprehension . Is it possible and if so, how?

```
listy =[x for x in range(6,100) if x % 3 == 0]
listy = listy + [x+20 for x in listy] + [x+40 for x in listy]
```

This prints out all numbers and I can sort it easily but I want a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
>>> [i for j in map(lambda x: (x, x+20, x+40), [x for x in range(6,100) if x % 3 == 0]) for i in j]

[6, 26, 46, 9, 29, 49, 12, 32, 52, 15, 35, 55, 18, 38, 58, 21, 41, 61, 24, 44, 64, 27, 47, 67, 30, 50, 70, 33, 53, 73, 36, 56, 76, 39, 59, 79, 42, 62, 82, 45, 65, 85, 48, 68, 88, 51, 71, 91, 54, 74, 94, 57, 77, 97, 60, 80, 100, 63, 83, 103, 66, 86, 106, 69, 89, 109, 72, 92, 112, 75, 95, 115, 78, 98, 118, 81, 101, 121, 84, 104, 124, 87, 107, 127, 90, 110, 130, 93, 113, 133, 96, 116, 136, 99, 119, 139]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can note that any number larger than 43 is possible to represent with combination of 3, 5 and 20 (it's not too hard to prove).
And only numbers not more than 43 which needs 20 are 26, 29, 32, 35, 38, 41.
So basically you can either hardcode all suitable values:

```
listy = [x in [6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 26, 27, 29, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, 38, 39, 41, 42] if x < MAX] # or any 43 < number < MAX
listy = [x for x in range(6, MAX) if x % 3 == 0] + [x in [26, 29, 32, 35, 38, 41] if x < MAX]] # other way
```

Also possible solution with list comprehensions:

```
listy =[x for x in range(6,MAX) if x % 3 == 0 or (x>=26 and (x-20)%3 == 0)]
```